# Not able to automate the alert box using selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

I am having an alert box for saving changes in a form. However, I am not able to automate the alert box using selenium. Here's an [image of the Alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRntN.png). I have already used the methods like :

```
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

but this is also not working.

HTML code for the alert:

```html
<div id="ngdialog2" class="ngdialog ngdialog-theme-default ng-scope" role="alertdialog" aria-labelledby="ngdialog2-aria-labelledby" aria-describedby="ngdialog2-aria-describedby">
   <div class="ngdialog-overlay" />
   <div class="ngdialog-content" role="document">
      <div class="ngdialog-message">
         <div class="dialog-header clearfix">
            <h3 id="ngdialog2-aria-labelledby" class="ng-binding">Confirm</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="dialog-content">
            <p id="ngdialog2-aria-describedby" class="ng-binding">Do you want to save?</p>
         </div>
         <div class="button-controls">
            <button class="button cancel-btn ng-binding" ng-click="closeThisDialog(false)">No</button>
            <button class="button btn-submit ng-binding" ng-click="closeThisDialog(true)">Yes</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: The dialog, as you have noticed, is not an alert... it's an HTML "dialog". The alerts that you are referring to are alerts displayed by the browser and do not consist of HTML. Treat it like any other HTML and write code. If you are still having issues, please post the code you have tried and what the result was so we can better help you.

Comment: jeefC she down voted my answer she is not interested to correct her self :)